# I am having some trouble embedding an image generated by a PHP script into a MIME email

Tags: php, image, mime

I am using Zencart to send out an email with a gift certificate to a customer. The certificate is generated by a php file using imagepng and I have no troubles using it to display on webpages with

```
echo "<img src=\"getImage.php\"/>".
```

However, when I try and do the same in the email script it wont display (though any standard images will). I assume this has something to do with it being dynamically generated but I can't seem to get around it. I have tried temporarily saving the image by giving imagepng a name generated by tempnam by doing this,

```
$fname = tempnam("", "img");
imagepng($im, $fname . ".png");
```

but for some reason it doesn't save the image.
I would like to use ob_get_contents but I am not sure how to go about it so that it gives me a value i can use inside of an image tag.

This has been driving me nuts the last couple of days. Any help would be appreciated.

Grace

Comment: [`imagepng($gd, $filename)`](http://php.net/imagepng) allows to save to a file directly. Have you tried that? Have you enabled `error_reporting`? What does it say?

Comment: My error log doesn't show anything wrong with the imagepng call. And I have tried doing this as well
    $fname="test.png";
    imagepng($im, $fname);

Comment: If possible I would like to avoid actually saving a copy of the image to file as this may result in some issues

Answer (score 0):

Emails are outside of your web, so you must to set the absolute path to the image:

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/yourimage.php"/>
```

Or include it in the email using base64 encoding, but it's more complex.

Comment: standard images are included using relative paths with no issues and adding the full path for the php file did not help :(
I will have a look at base64 encoding

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to contain the image in the email message, too.  If your image is dynamically created at sending time, you need to run the PHP script at sending time, and include the result in the message.  If you want the image to be generated when the client views the message, then like @Laleft says, you have to have a full URL in the link in the `<img>`tag.

If you want to refer to an attached image, assign a Content-Id: and refer to it with a `cid:` link, something like this:

```
From: you <spammer@example.com>
To: recipient <victim@example.net>
Subject: Buy V!agra Ciali$
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary="moo"

--moo
Content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body><img="cid:moo.png"></body></html>

--moo
Content-type: image/png
Content-disposition: inline
Content-id: "moo.png"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

///base64/encoded/output/of/PHP/script/goes/here//==

--moo--
```